# Other peoples photos in my camera uploads folder

Tags: dropbox

My Samsung Galaxy 3 android phone is linked to my Dropbox account so that photos I take on my phone are automatically uploaded to the Camera Uploads folder. Suddenly lots of strange photos have appeared in this folder and my photos aren't appearing.

These photos look like a family in the Middle East, I am in Europe.
My questions are:

1. who do I complain to - Dropbox, Samsung or Google/Android?
2. If I delete these unknown photos will someone else be losing their precious family photos
3. If I am seeing their photos who is seeing mine!?

Comment: looks like someone else linked to your account.

Comment: You need to contact Dropbox! BTW i'd suggest changing your password immediately!

Comment: Are there any devices you may have lost or had stolen that are linked to your account?

Answer (score 2):

Change the password on DropBox straight away.

Then move the photos into a folder in case anyone gets in touch.

Make sure that your new password is a strong one and not easily guessed.

Then let DropBox know what happened and what you've done.